# Null Getter, when split throwing exception

Tags: java

I have an array

`String [] array = account.getDetails().split(',');`

the account details is sometimes null, how to avoid the exception?

I did something like that, but that does not like pretty.

```
if (account.getDetails() == null) 
{
   account.setDetails("");
}

String[] array = account.getDetails().split(',');
```

That avoid throwing the `NullPointerException`, is this okay or is there a better way?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile (you can't split a `String` on a `char`). And your if-statement is perfectly acceptable. We know nothing about what you want to `array` to be if `account.getDetails()` **is** `null`, so we can't help much anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a "prettier" way of doing it, then this is a spot that seems decent for the '?' operator (called the ternary operator)

```
String[] array = account.getDetails() == null? new String[]{""} : account.getDetails().split(",");
```

You could also change the getter or the setter/constructor so that the getDetails() method never returns a null (because it won't or because it never has a null at all).

```
public String getDetails() {
    return details == null? "" : details;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

<s>Your implementation is fine</s> (more below), but you can avoid calling `split(String)` on an empty string and do something like this:

```
String[] array;
if (account.getDetails() == null) {
   array = new String[0];
} else {
   array = account.getDetails().split(",");
}
```

Be careful that your implementation would return an array with one empty string if the input was `null`, this will return an empty array.

As pointed out by @MarkAdelsberger you should not change the value directly on the object, this is known as god behavior.

Comment: `String salaryDetails = array[0];` cannot use your code, because after in the code I have string that takes the array[0], and that causes pop-up that this array may not be initialized.

Comment: The array will surely be initialized, there must be something else wrong.

Comment: I would argue that OP's implementation is *not* fine, because it unnecessarily changes the property value in cases when it starts out null - which in many cases would not be god behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Null check with `if else` statement is ok. Also needs to be mentioned that in java8 an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) was introduced, that help to avoid null checking. With optional it will look like:

```
String[] strings = Optional.ofNullable(account.getDetails())
    .map(s -> s.split(",")).orElse(new String[0]);
```

Comment: Up-voted because it shows the correct (as of Java 8) way to deal with potentially-null properties; BUT I disagree with the statement that OP's check is ok.  If would be ok (though perhaps dated) to check for null and provide an alternative expression, but what OP did was to change the property in code that probably isn't meant to be doing so

Answer (score 1):

So here is the good way in my opinion, first you check if the details is not `null` using `?` if it's not `null` you just do the `split` and assign result to variable `array`, else you assign empty array of strings since details were `null`:

```
String details = account.getDetails();
String[] array = details != null ? details.split(",") : new String[0];
```